# Intermittent HTML Input Value Not Populating

Tags: php, html, forms, input

My project receives a list of values all strings. I want the values to populate a form, which all the other values do fine, but when Im placing values into the dates - it randomly works.

As a test I echo out the results at the start of the page

```
 <?php echo($thisDate[17]);
 echo("<br>");
 echo($thisDate[15]); ?>
```

The results are as expected.

```
30/04/2017
04/06/2017
```

But later on in the same php code

```
<td>Date Of Birth<br>
    <input
        type="text"
        name="dob"
        form="driver_form"
        placeholder="DOB"
        tabindex=10
        id="datepicker"
        value="<?php echo($thisDate[15]);?>">
</td>
```

and

```
<td>Badege Valid Till<br>
    <input
        type="text"
        name="badgeValid"
        form="driver_form"
        placeholder="Valid Till"
        tabindex=13
        id="datepickerB"
        value="<?php echo($thisDate[17]); ?>">
</td>
```

I thought I had the problem resolved as it seemed to work, but now it does not again.

Comment: Use date() to format the dates. You may need to use other functions depending upon which type the date is stored. What do the ones that don't work display? are the vars empty?

Comment: Should they still not populate as they are passed as strings that are going into a <input type="text"

Comment: The problem I have found is around the id="datepicker". It does not seem to want to populate form with the datepicker linked.